# Using "is" or "does"?

Tags: word-choice, indefinite-article, interrogatives

Which one is correct? This is the title of my blog.

1. Is arrival of virtual router, a death knell for physical router.
2. Does arrival of virtual router, a death knell for physical router.

Second question.

Do  you suggest to use "a" before virtual router or  physical router.

Answer (score 2):

> Which one is correct. This is the title of my blog.
>
> Is arrival of virtual router, a death knell for physical router.
>
> Does arrival of virtual router, a death knell for physical router.
>
> Second question.
>
> Do you suggest to use "a" before virtual router or physical router.

None of the options seem correct according to Standard Written English.
Corresponding (better) sentences may be:
1. Is the arrival of Virtual Router a death knell for Physical Router?
2. Does the arrival of Virtual Router ring the Death Knell for Physical Routers?

---

Use of articles - a and the

A few examples are as follows:

- A virtual router can help you in setting up you network without a physical router.
- The Virtual Router is the latest development in the field of routers.

---

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when it comes to an internet title or a newspaper headline, the verb *to be* (*is*) is not going to be used often. It is a stative verb that has no action to it, so it is eliminated from headlines and titles. *Does* is usually an auxiliary verb in many headlines, as it is necessary to ask a yes/no question.

For the title of a blog post, I suggest:

**A**

> Does the arrival of the virtual router mean (or sound) the death knell for the physical router?

or

**B**

> Virtual routers: the death knell for the physical router?

**Version A**: since you are talking about routers, which are count nouns, you can use "the" before both noun phrases. *The* makes a definite reference to both routers, and definite references are often used in this kind of context. See examples below.

**Version B**: With the zero-article, *Virtual routers* is an indefinite reference. It means an unspecified number of virtual routers, or *virtual routers* in general.

But there are many more possibilities than A and B. There are dozens of possibilities.

Here are a few examples. Note that only #3 uses *to be*, and it is included because it is necessary to refer to the future. You might also look at the variety of articles before *death knell*.

1:

> Does **the** arrival of the Internet mean **the** end of natural monopolies? ([source](http://www.eleven-strategy.com/does-the-arrival-of-the-internet-mean-the-end-of-natural-monopolies/))

2:

> **The** end of Christianity in the Middle East could mean **the** demise of Arab secularism ([source](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/jul/23/arab-christians-secular-arabs-isis-middle-east-minorities))

3:

> **The** Privatisation of the NHS: Why It Will Be the Death Knell for **the** Tory-Led Coalition Government ([source](http://www.andyworthington.co.uk/2012/03/20/the-privatisation-of-the-nhs-why-it-will-be-the-death-knell-for-the-tory-led-coalition-government/))

4:

> Does Mimi Alford's New Memoir Finally Mean the Death Knell for **the** Camelot Myth of JFK? ([source](http://historynewsnetwork.org/article/144883))

5:

> The death knell rings for **the** Jarvis Street bike lanes ([source](http://www.blogto.com/city/2012/11/the_death_knell_rings_for_the_jarvis_street_bike_lanes/))

6:

> Online shopping could mean the death knell for high-street stores ([source](http://www.carlow-nationalist.ie/2014/12/05/online-shopping-could-mean-the-death-knell-for-high-street-stores/))

Note: Both *Online shopping* and *high-street stores* work better *without* an article, that is, with an indefinite reference. Since high-street stores is a plural count noun, the zero-article means an indefinite reference, *ie* it is talking about an indefinite number of *high-street stores*, which can mean **all** *high-street stores*.

For the same reason, one can find:

7:

> Amazon: a death knell for Indian bookstores

8:

> Cheap mobiles and texting sound death knell for **the** pager ([source](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1473635/Cheap-mobiles-and-texting-sound-death-knell-for-the-pager.html))

9:

> Will roads sound a death knell for **the** porter/pony? ([source](http://www.kuenselonline.com/will-roads-sound-a-death-knell-for-the-porterpony/))

Numbers 8 and 9 are like my Example B. Use the zero-article before the opening noun and the definite article before the thing that is on its way out.

Answer (score 1):

*Is the virtual router the physical router's death knell?*

Literally a death knell is a bell, so you might say 'does the virtual router ring the physical router's death knell.'

Comment: Small quibble - literally, "knell" is the sound the bell makes, not the bell itself.  The rest of your answer still holds. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/knell